# What does a form tag do behind the scene

Tags: html, forms

If I want to send data back to the server from user input I know I need to use the form tag.

But why do I need the form tag, what does a form tag do behind the scenes?

I've only been in web development for less than a year, so please forgive me if my question is beginner question.

Edit:  I know a form is used to denote a part of the page that is interactive and data between the from tags will be sent back to the server.

So, is the tag, just a tag, is there another piece of technology that takes the data from the page and returns the data to the server?

Edit 2: From comments and more specific web searches, I found out that the form tag is just that.  A tag.  It defines something on a page and does not do anything.  All is okay now.

Comment: It doesn't "do" anything itself, much less "behind the scenes." It only tells the browser that the inner HTML is a form, and it may tell the browser how to send the data somewhere (with, for example, the `method` and `action` attributes). After that, though, you need server-side technology to do something with the data. If you need more information, you need to be more precise and state your question more clearly.

Comment: @EdCottrell Oh, okay.  I see.  so the tag is just that.  A marker.  Cool.

Comment: That's all *any* HTML tag does (hence the name, HyperText *Markup* Language).

Answer (score 0):

The form tag validates and with html 5 it means it doesn't call the server immediately. It can do a quick check before it attempts to post. E.g. does the email box look like an email address.

The advantage of this is it reduces costs as you're not unnecessarily calling the server. When the form thinks it looks good it will send the info to the back end.

Get and post messages are sent either getting information (reading) or it might be posting (writing).

I think that's what you're after.

Comment: Kind of.  From the comment on my question above, I learned that a form tag is just that, a tag and that tag does nothing special, it's just a marker for the browser.

But, I also did not know that about the form tag.

Comment: As Ed mentions its also part of semantic HTML to give meaning to the page. I didn't think you were specifically asking about that